# Django infinity redirect in IIS behind a proxy server turned on SSL

Tags: django, redirect, iis

I have a problem with Python Django when deploying on Windows Server.
Let's summary my situation:

**End user** <--https--> **Proxy Server will SSL** <--http--> **Django on Win Server**

The communication between End-User with Proxy server is HTTPS, the commnunication between Proxy Server with Django is HTTP.

So, when the user browse the web site, proxy server tried to redirect to https and passing to Django, Django processed the request and return http to proxy, proxy server tried to redirect its to https => that's caused the CSRF failed => loop infinity here.

I have read the django doc here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header

```
Warning

Modifying this setting can compromise your site’s security. Ensure you fully understand your setup before changing it.

Make sure ALL of the following are true before setting this (assuming the values from the example above):

- Your Django app is behind a proxy.
- Your proxy strips the X-Forwarded-Proto header from all incoming requests. In other words, if end users include that header in their requests, the proxy will discard it.
- Your proxy sets the X-Forwarded-Proto header and sends it to Django, but only for requests that originally come in via HTTPS.
If any of those are not true, you should keep this setting set to None and find another way of determining HTTPS, perhaps via custom middleware.
```

=> My Django app is behind a proxy, the incoming request come from https, so I had applied the settings:

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

but it is still redirect infinity.

So anyone has the same issue, please suggest me some ideas?

Comment: Could you post your IIS proxy configuration? Because it also require custom request header HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO being added by IIS Server. Did you achieve this with httpmodule?

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot have the permission to touch on this Proxy server :(

Answer (score 0):

Seem no one has this issue like me, so I decided to switch to another solution by using the Apache httpd with IIS as a Proxy. 
Detail about it for some one to reference, I will update later.